# Does an object's trajectory effect its kinetic energy?

Tags: energy, kinematics, potential-energy

I was wondering whether I could calculate the kinetic energy of an object, with mass m travelling along this trajectory, at point 2, by calculating its potential energy at point 1 with the point of reference being point two, the height would therefore be $h+R$. This makes sense to me, because the sum of an object's kinetic and potential energy is constant and the object has $0$ kinetic energy at point 1 because it is not yet moving so its velocity is also $0$. And at point 2 it has $0$ potential energy, because its height from the point of reference is $0$. Therefore

$$E_p + E_k = \text{constant}.$$

At point 1 where $E_k = 0$:

$$E_p + 0 = \text{constant}.$$

At point 2 where $E_p = 0$:

$$0 + E_k = \text{constant}.$$

Therefore $E_p$ at point 1 equals $E_k$ at point 2. It all makes sense to me but I still feel this shouldn't work. What do you think?

[image]

Comment: You're right in absence of friction and no other non-conservative forces acting on the mass

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your reasoning is correct. Assuming no friction, the only force acting here is gravity which is a so-called conservative force that does not care about the path taken. The object undergoes the same change in potential and kinetic energy when moving between two points, regardless of the path taken between those points. The change in kinetic/potential energy depends only on the height difference between points.

If there were non-conservative forces like friction acting here, the trajectory would make a difference. You could imagine that if the object slides along the path with friction, it would lose some energy to friction with every inch moved. In this case, a very short direct path would lose less energy than a long, winding path. If friction is acting here, you'd need to know not just the starting and ending points, but the path taken between them.

Comment: Thank you, this is very helpful, I was also wondering if it would be possible to determine whether an object could get to point 3 by checking if Ep at point 1 in relation to point two is larger or equal to Ep at point 3 in relation to point two, which would means that the condition would be that r+R<=h+R, subtract R from both sides and the final condition is that R<=h. Is this correct?

Answer (score 1):

**Kinetic energy.** We can use the second principle of dynamics for a point mass as,

$m \dot{\mathbf{v}} = \mathbf{F}$,

in the time derivative of the kinetic energy

$\dfrac{d K}{dt} = \dfrac{d}{dt} \left( \dfrac{1}{2} m |\mathbf{v}|^2 \right) = m \dot{ \mathbf{v}} \cdot \mathbf{v} = \mathbf{F} \cdot \mathbf{v}$,

to find that the kinetic energy of a point mass changes if the power of forces acting on it is non-zero.

**Mechanical energy.** It we split the contribution of the forces acting on the mass as the sum of the contributions of the conservative and non-conservative forces

$\mathbf{F} = \mathbf{F}^{c} + \mathbf{F}^{nc} = - \nabla V + \mathbf{F}^{nc}$,

where $V$ is the potential energy, we can rewrite the equation for time derivative of the kinetic energy as

$\dfrac{d K}{dt} = -\nabla V \cdot \mathbf{v} + \mathbf{F}^{nc} \cdot \mathbf{v}$,

recognize that $\nabla V \cdot \mathbf{v} = \dfrac{d V}{dt}$ is the time derivative of the potential energy as felt by the point mass, to get

$\dfrac{d E^{mec}}{dt} = \mathbf{F}^{nc} \cdot \mathbf{v}$,

where $E^{mec} = K + V$. From this equation we can find the conservation of the total energy if the non-conservative forces have no net power on the system,

$0 = \mathbf{F}^{nc} \cdot \mathbf{v} = \frac{dE^{mec}}{dt}$$\quad \rightarrow \quad$$E^{mec} = \text{const.}$,

as it is when the mass experiences no friction, and thus the reaction is orthogonal to the trajectory.

Comment: "If the point experiences no friction on the path... 0=F⋅v=dK/dt." This does not seem to be true. The kinetic energy can change even when there is no friction. It does change as the ball changes it's position wrt the ground. (The path is not always perpendicular to the force of gravity.) Can you explain what you mean or remove this part of the answer?

Comment: Right, it should have gone in the second part of the answer. edited

Comment: Thanks, looks better. I upvoted.

Comment: thanks for the review. it was wrong before, and it could have been very misleading for the OP

Answer (score 0):

To add to the already good answer, what you are using here is actually the 1st law of thermodynamics which defines the concept of energy conservation: Energy cannot disappear nor come into existence from thin air, so it either has to be added/taken away from your system or it was already there to start with:

$$\sum E_\text{now}=\sum E_\text{later}+E_\text{added/removed}\\
\sum E_\text{now}=\sum E_\text{later}+W+Q.$$

Adding/removing energy happens either as heat $Q$ or work $W$. If you have a scenario between points 1 and 2 of no energy input/removal, $W=Q=0$, and if only potential and kinetic energies are involved, then

$$E_{k,1}+E_{p,1}=E_{k,2}+E_{p,2}+0+0.$$

And from here you can substitute in your correct guesses of $E_{k,1}=0$ and $E_{p,2}=0$, which results in $E_{p,1}=E_{k,2}$.

With this you can now calculate all sorts of properties depending on what you are given/have measured initially. You might be able to find the speed at point 2, the height up to point 1, the mass and so on.

The fact that you solely by such energy considerations can solve for kinematic properties like these, is an enormous strength of the 1st law of thermodynamics in mechanics. You can avoid the tedious motion equations, you can avoid calculations of accelerations from forces, you can avoid considering angles, directions and trigonometry etc. and instead just consider energy. It may feel like it shouldn't be so simple, but if you believe in the energy conservation concept as a law of nature of our world then it really is that simple. Neat. Only if you cannot approximate the ideal scenario of no energy transfers will this approach be problematic - but so will many other approaches.